# strange int values read by read function

Tags: c, matrix, posix

I am doing an exercize, where you are required to read on a 32bit Little endian machine a binary file of this kind:

> 30002000100020003000400050006000

This kind of file describes a matrix with int elements. The first two ints (3000 and 2000) describes the rows and columns  dimensions of matrix.

I am having some troubles, so I started doing some debugging, and I found out that

```
c = read(fd, &a, sizeof(int));
```

writes strange values in a, not a normal int, but something like 808464435. I am programming on a 64bit machine, Fedora 18, but I saw with

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));
```

that ints are still of 4 byte.

Here the complete code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



int openFile(const char* path)
{
    int fd;
    fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("error in file opening\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fd;
}

int readInt(int fd)
{
    int a,c;
    c = read(fd, &a, sizeof(int));
    if(c == -1)
    {
        perror("error in read\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return a;
}

void fillMatrix(int fd,int* matrix, int* rows, int* columns)
{
    *rows = readInt(fd);
    *columns = readInt(fd);
    matrix = calloc(((*rows) * (*columns)) + 1, sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 1; i <= (*rows) * (*columns); i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = readInt(fd);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


    int fdA;
    int rowsA, columnsA;
    int *matrixA;
    fdA = openFile("/home/caterpillar/workspace/18Luglio2012/src/matrixA.txt");
    fillMatrix(fdA, matrixA, &rowsA, &columnsA);

    for(int i = 1; i <= rowsA * columnsA; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", matrixA[i]);
    }


    close(fdA);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the file literally look like `30002000100020003000400050006000` if you open it in a text editor?

Comment: I suspect that it's actually a text file, not a binary as you have stated..

Comment: The exam is an exam you have to do with pencil and paper, so I am trying to re-create it on my computer. Probably I messed up something in creating the file. Can't I create it with a simple text editor?

Comment: @Caterpillar if the file should be binary, you can create it in a hexadecimal editor. But the simplest way would be to write a simple program that generates it for you.

Comment: 808464435 is not a strange value, it's a parfectly fine integer. They all are. It is also `0x30303033` in hex, which seems to indicate that your file contains text and not binary data. `0x30` is the ASCII encoding for the digit `0`, and `0x33` is the digit `3`.